# User selects background color with HTML color codes

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to find a javascript code that allows a user to type an HTML color code into a textbox or prompt box, and having the background color of the page change to the color code entered. As of Present, This does not work: 
     
     
     
        
            header {
                color: green;
                font-size: 250%;
                background: blue;
            }
            body {
                background: green;
            }

```
        <header>
    <center>
    Test
    </center>
</header>
    <center>
        <br>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input type="text" class="inp" placeholder="6 digit hex value">
 <input type="submit" class="sub" value="Set Background Color">
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.sub').click(function() {
$('.body').css('background-color',"#"+$('.inp').val());
});
});
</script>
    </center>
 </div>
 </html>
```

Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks
-A

Comment: If you'll share more about what you have already done, people may be more willing to answer. For example, do you already know how to create a textbox or a prompt? Can you show us that code?

Comment: Did you even try...`<input type="text" onblur="document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.value;" id="color">`

Comment: did you search the problem on google ? what did you find ?

Comment: I did, of course, search first. I found nothing involving color code input.

Comment: What would be nice is instead of criticizing my ways of finding data, or coding in general... is actually answering my question. Thanks

Comment: I made an edit... the code above does not work. Any idea why?

Comment: Check the answer i posted, try value #555555 or any other hex code value. The event occurs onblur, which is when you move out of the input box.No more space to comment, please check my answer, have addressed the issue in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer with JSFiddle

What you need is this

```
<input type="text" onblur="document.body.style.backgroundColor = this.value;" id="color">
```

You could go further and separate this into functions.
Here is the working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2Xgfr/1098/)

This works both for text inputs(red,blue,orange) as well as hex codes(#000000).

For your code, here is the correct code.Body isn't a class, it's a tag.So no selector required.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$('.sub').click(function() {
    $('body').css('background-color',"#"+$('.inp').val());
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What if I wanted to change the header background color instead? I just tried `<input type="text" onblur="document.header.style.backgroundColor = this.value;" id="color">` and it doesn't work

Comment: Simply use this for the JSFIDDLE method `<input type="text" onblur="document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.backgroundColor = this.value;" id="color">`                                 If you went ahead with the other way of doing it as shown above, then do this. .`$('header').css('background-color',"#"+$('.inp').val());` . Essentially, header being a tag, can be fetched directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sub').click(function() {
    $('.body').css('background-color',"#"+$('.inp').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="body">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="inp" placeholder="6 digit hex value">
<input type="submit" class="sub" value="Set Background Color">
</div>
```